# Redirect to intended url after visiting many page in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want my website visitors' to redirect to the intended url after login. Suppose, I've a protected page `dashboard`. If any guest tries to access to `dashboard`, he get redirected to `login` page. Now, Instead of login he visited other pages and then returned to `login` page intentionally. How can I redirect him to the previously intended `dashboard` page after this login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how you're handling the login action, for example if using the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware you can make the following change:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            // return redirect('/home');
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This will redirect the user to whatever page they intended on accessing and send them to /dashboard by default. You could further extend this by using a different fallback URL depending on the users role in case guests or administrators need to land at a different page after login.